# Gradle: Execution Failed For Task

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Hi I just tried to do a example program of Android Tab Layout With Swipe. I added android support libraries in the lib folder. I added appcompat v4 and v7 in that. After that I clicked sync project with gradle files. Then I entered code then everything went and I found no error in code but when I try to run the program its showing me this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/ArrayRes.class
```

And my build.gradle file contains this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.eugene.swipeabletablayout"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

In my code there is no problem but I don't know why I am getting this error.

I tried to search for this issue in SOF but I didn't find any answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the Android support libraries from the libs directory.  Since you are using gradle and have indicated a compile dependency with `appcompat-v7` you do not need to include the JARs manually.  This is causing a conflict at build time with duplicate symbols.  Listing it as a compile dependency will cause gradle to work with Maven to pull the lib automatically (and its dependencies.)

Comment: can i remove the complile dependency and include a jar file manually, will that work for me?

Comment: It depends on whether you are using any other gradle dependencies which have their own dependencies.  Otherwise, the default `build.gradle` file that Android Studio generates for an app will automatically include any jar file placed in the module's `libs` subdirectory.