# Android Gradle - Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. >

Tags: java, android, dependencies

Whever I try to debug and deploy my android application (in Android Studio 1.5.1) I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/geronimo/osgi/locator/Activator.class
```

Since then, I received this error after adding this dependency

```
compile 'com.github.wmixvideo:nfe:1.0.23'
```

Here is a current copy of my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.gerenciarsc.nfce"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.wmixvideo:nfe:1.0.23'
}
```

How to resolve?

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864267/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-error-in-my-project-while-i-adde/33864437#33864437

Comment: I think probably this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276853/gradle-execution-failed-for-task) answers your question.