# TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, exception, android-studio

I am getting the following error when I build my project in android studio

com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/annotation/ArrayRes.class

My build.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.instagram_project"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

This is the screenshot of my lib folder in the project
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDjL4.jpg

Comment: post your logcat error stack here ..

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Android support libraries from the libs directory. Since you are using gradle and have indicated a compile dependency with `appcompat-v7` you do not need to include the JARs manually. This is causing a conflict at build time with duplicate symbols. Listing it as a compile dependency will cause gradle to work with Maven to pull the lib automatically (and its dependencies.)

for more detail look here.[java.util.zip.ZipException in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276853/gradle-execution-failed-for-task//)