# Shared dependencies in multi-project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a multi-project set up as followed:

- App (Main project)

  - Lib1 (AAR)
  - Lib2 (Another Gradle project)

What I need to do, is to add a third-party library as a dependency in App as well as Lib2. But when I set the dependencies in both build.gradle, I receive an error like this:

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task  ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: PATHTODEPENDENCY.class

Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276853/gradle-execution-failed-for-task

Comment: You are adding twice the same dependency. Check the jar files